# How to make privileged user

Tags: ssh

I get this message when I try to SSH into my Raspberry Pi after having run `sudo shutdown`:

> System is going down. Unprivileged users are not permitted to log in anymore

I thought the default account was a privileged user, because I can run `sudo` commands without ever having to enter my password.

How can I make the account a privileged user?

The command I use to connect is: `ssh rpi`

The `~/.ssh/config` entry for it looks like this:

```
Host rpi
  HostName rpi.local
  Port 2222
  User hawk
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: I believe once a shutdown is in progress only `root` would be allowed to log in

Comment: Ok, it's quite a misleading error message. 1. It should just say `root`, not "privileged users" (plural! when there is only one root). Everyone knows root. 2. Root login is disabled (by default on Raspberry Pi) so it should just say that: "only root can log in, but root login is disabled". Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I said "I believe" - so I could be wrong

Comment: Did you wait for shutdown to finish BEFORE trying to login?

Comment: @Milliways no, I ran `sudo shutdown`, logged out and then realized I forgot something and wanted to cancel the shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

Do you tried to use sudo user to shutdown ?

To login with root do `su -` and use the sudo password.

After this you can use `shutdown`